# how to use SHA256 with salt(some key) in swift

Tags: swift, sha256, commoncrypto

I found we can hash some string with CommonCrypto.
and I see some examples but they don't use salt.
how can i use the SHA256 with salt?

Answer (score 5):

Complete solution for Swift 4:

```
extension Data {

    var hexString: String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

    var sha256: Data {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }

}

extension String {

    func sha256(salt: String) -> Data {
        return (self + salt).data(using: .utf8)!.sha256
    }

}
```

Example:

```
let hash = "test".sha256(salt: "salt").hexString
```

Answer (score 4):

Combine your indata with a salt and run the hash calculation;

```
func hash(input: String, salt: String) -> String {
    let toHash = input + salt

    // TODO: Calculate the SHA256 hash of "toHash" and return it
    // return sha256(toHash)

    // Return the input data and hash for now
    return toHash
}

print(hash("somedata", salt: "1m8f")) // Prints "somedata1m8f"
```

Comment: Yepp, that should do it!

Comment: Most of the time, this is exactly fine, but there is one security vulnerability to be aware of. If both the input and salt can be of variable lengths, this can inject a vulnerability. For example, in this scheme, if the salt is the username, then hashing `abc` and a username of `dennis` is the same as hashing `abcd` and a username of `ennis`. This can be resolved by separating the pieces with a character that is not permitted in the data (`\0` is a common choice; I also use `:` for convenience when that is a forbidden character), or by ensuring that the salt is of fixed length.